# Add line to stacked barchart with categorical x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, categorical-data

I'm trying to add a `geom_line` to this plot but no luck.

[image]

This might have worked if not the x-axis are of categorical type (chr).
I'm trying this with no effect:
`geom_line(aes(y=nettoforandring_mellan_ar_1_och_2, group=arsintervall))`
where `nettoforandring_mellan_ar_1_och_2` is my col. with the netto of the stacked bars for each categorical yr, and `arsintervall` is the categorical x-axis.

**-> any ideas?**

Thanks!

Comment: Very difficult to say without having the data that produced the plot, which is why we suggest a minimal reproducible example rather than just an image and a partial code snippet. However, it looks like you should have `group = Manad` in your geom line, and you will also need `position = 'stack'` in your `geom_line` call. If this doesn't work for you please include your entire plotting code and some reproducible data using `dput`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP, please add a **Reproducible Example** in the future (*data and full code which alone can produce an example plot that showcases your problem*).  However, the core question relates to adding `geom_line()` across a categorical (discrete) x axis.

#### REPRODUCIBLE EXAMPLE

I can recreate the same sort of question using `mtcars`:

```
library(ggplot2)

p <-
  ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=factor(gear), y=wt)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill=factor(cyl)))
```

[image]

#### SOLUTION

Since categorical (discrete) axes aren't "connected", `ggplot2` will not by default draw a line between values on the x axis.  It treats any line drawn as being connected only by y values.  Therefore, you get vertical lines only when you do this:

```
p + geom_line(linewidth=0.8)
```

[image]

To connect across x axis values, you have to "force" the connection by telling `ggplot2` to put all the points into the same group.  Do this via mapping `group=1` or `group=` literally any random string, value, etc.

```
p + geom_line(aes(group=1), linewidth=0.8)
```

[image]

While unnecessary here, if you wanted to only draw a line with something like average values (often the case when wanting to draw a line across stacked barplots), you can use `stat_summary(geom="line")` and apply the same logic.  The code below produces a line that only connects y value points which are the mean for each x position.

```
p + stat_summary(
    aes(group="big scary monster"),  # see how group can equal anything here?
    geom="line", linewidth=0.8)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I did apperently not think correctly - I thought I would group on the variable that I want it to follow - however it just want a variable that doesn't change with the dataset? Passing the aes-argument with group=1 worked fine, as I'm sure any string would as per you info! I also passed an y-argument inside the aes on that col.-data i wanted to show - if you do not do that it plots a line for every stacked bar-serie.